# Adding NavigationView to XAML: "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key NavigationViewItemDefaultStyle"

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I am new to Windows development, and I am trying to create an application using the new NavigationView control (currently in beta).
I have the 16190 SDK installed and targeted for my project. My computer is running *v.1703, Build 16215.1000*.

However, when I add the NavigationView tag to my XAML file, my poject no longer builds, with the following `XamlParseException` exception:

`"Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key NavigationViewItemDefaultStyle"`

I try to use the Navigation View as the root element of my page, and I have no additional code in the project.
What could be the problem? Are there any specific steps I need to take to enable development with the beta SDK?

Comment: This is a bug in *16215* unfortunately. You will have to wait for the next build or reverse to previous one.

Comment: That's right. I rolled back to Build 16199, and everything is working properly now. Thank you! You can post your comment as an answer, so I could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/221) in *16215* and if you roll back to *16199* it should be working again.

Note you will need to declare the `NavigationViewItem`s in code-behind for it to work, this is just another bug unfortunately.

```
<NavigationView x:Name="MyNavigationView"
                Header="Fluent Layout"
                AlwaysShowHeader="False"
                IsSettingsVisible="True">
    <Frame x:Name="RootFrame"
           Margin="24" />
</NavigationView>
```

---

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // The following cannot be done in XAML in this build yet.
    MyNavigationView.AddMenuItem(Symbol.AllApps, "All Applications", (s, e) => RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AppsPage)), true);
    MyNavigationView.AddMenuItem(Symbol.Video, "Games", (s, e) => RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(GamesPage)));
    MyNavigationView.AddMenuItem(Symbol.Calendar, "Calendar", (s, e) => RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(CalendarPage)));
    MyNavigationView.AddMenuItemSeparator();
    MyNavigationView.AddMenuItem(Symbol.Admin, "My Account", (s, e) => RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AccountPage)));

    MyNavigationView.SettingsInvoked += (s, e) => RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
    RootFrame.Navigate(typeof(AppsPage));
}
```

I will update the answer once both bugs are fixed.